# How to convert HTML framesets / frames to iframes in a PHP setting - 2020 scenario and solution

Tags: php, html, iframe, frame, frameset

Much expert advice has been read here on this topic. Though, sometimes this was very general and did not incorporate the suggestion **not** to use Bootstrap's or Flexbox' solutions to this dilemma.

For all those of you who have a "historic" HTML frameset with several frames I would like to show you the way how I did this transformation from the original PHP code files. Being very grateful for all the professional advice I personally had been able to collect on stack overflow, I would like to return something here.

The basic layout structure is like this:

```
    +---------------------------------------------------------+
    | (1)                                                     |
    +---------------------------------------------------------+
    | (2)                                                     |
    +---------------------------------------------------------+
    | (3) |                 frameBody                   | (4) |
    |     |                                             |     |
    |     |                                             |     |
    |     |                                             |     |
    |     |                                             |     |
    |     |                                             |     |
    |     |                                             |     |
    |     |                                             |     |
    +---------------------------------------------------------+
    | (5)                                                     |
    +---------------------------------------------------------+
```

Legend:

(1) - headerTitle; (2) - frameMenu; (3) - userMenu; (4) - patientMenu; (5) - footerTitle.

After having logged in successfully from `login.php`, I am being forwarded to `site.php` which takes over the steering of the entire website. In this file, all the conditions for switching from conditions to conditions and, thus, to corresponding other PHP files is managed.

`site.php`, however, also takes care of the principal layout of the website, here in the old frameset / frame / noframes way (please excuse the lengthiness of the code example, but I want to show you how nicely short and well-structured an iframe solution can be):

```
    <?php
        // Lots of definitions and introductory stuff, not relevant here
    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=<?= strtolower($CHARSET) ?>" />
        <meta name="author" content="whoever" />
        <meta name="date" content="<?= date('r', filectime($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'])) ?>" />
    <title><?= $sCompanyName ?></title>
    </head>

    <frameset name="alles" cols="20,*,20" framespacing="0" frameborder="0" border="0" />
        <frameset rows="20,50,120,*,40,20" framespacing="0" frameborder="0" border="0" />
            <frame name="headerTitle" src="frameHeader.php" scrolling="no" noresize="noresize" />
            <frame name="frameMenu" src="frameMenu.php" scrolling="no" noresize="noresize" />

    <?php
        if (isset($_REQUEST['sBody']) && $_REQUEST['sBody'] == 'login')
        echo '<frame name="frameBody" src="login.php' . $sLanguageString . '">';
        else {
    ?>

            <frameset name="Frame1" cols="225,1,*,1,225" framespacing="0" frameborder="0" border="0">
                <frame name="userMenu" id="userMenu" src="userMenu.php" />
                <frame name="frameBody" src="<?= $sBody . (strlen($sURLParameterString) > 1 ? $sURLParameterString : '') ?>" />
                <frame name="patientMenu" id="patientMenu" src="patientMenu.php"/>
            </frameset>
            <frame name="footerTitle" src="frameFooter.php" scrolling="no" noresize="noresize" />
        </frameset>

    <?php
        }
    ?>

        <noframes>
        <body>

    <?php
        setSysMsg($oSysMsg->getExpression('general', 'noFrameSupport', 'This site is based on frames. But your browser doesn\'t support frames.<br />Your should choose another internet browser.'));
        echo getLastSysMsg();
    ?>

        </body>
        </noframes>
    </frameset>
    </html>
```

What are the obstacles now for an easy conversion?

Answer (score 0):

They all refer to my style of working only (apart from other professional skills you can read about in my profile I have developed large documentation and data analysis suites [WAMP, LAMP, MAMP] for handling special types of medical documentation), but if you find yourself in a similar timely condition, this situation may be similar to your own mindset:

Obstacle #1:
Ready-made solutions for the implementation of grids such as Bootstrap or Flexbox can be done as well, but using their CSS and JS files often needs a lot of individual adaptation if you want to have sizes, shapes, and colours your way.

Obstacle #2:
I personally prefer to experiment in a small, easy to conceive setting before embedding my solution into a bigger structure such as Bootstrap and Flexbox (and possibly others, too).

Obstacle #3:
I simply do not have the time to sit in front of the screen for hours and hours to check out some layout stuff when I dearly need to get data analyses and evaluations done.

Thus, after experimenting with WampServer on my localhost, I have found the following solution:

```
    <?php
        // Same lots of definitions and introductory stuff, again not relevant here
    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="whatever">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=<?= strtolower($CHARSET) ?>" />
        <meta name="date" content="<?= date('r', filectime($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'])) ?>" />
        <title><?= $sCompanyName ?></title>
    </head>

    <div>
        <iframe style="top:0px; width:100%; height:40px; border:2px red; background-color:grey; display:block; position:fixed;" id="headerTitle" name="headerTitle" scrolling="no" frameborder="1" marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px" src="frameHeader.php" /></iframe>
    </div>

    <div>
        <iframe style="top:40px; width:100%; height:120px; border:2px red; background-color:grey; display:block; position:fixed;" id="frameMenu" name="frameMenu" scrolling="no" frameborder="1" marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px" src="frameMenu.php" /></iframe>
    </div>

    <?php
        if (isset($_REQUEST['sBody']) && $_REQUEST['sBody'] == 'login')
        echo '<iframe name="frameBody" src="login.php' . $sLanguageString . '">';
        else {
    ?>

    <div style="float:left;">
        <iframe style="top:160px; width:225px; height:100%; border:2px blue; background-color:grey; display:inline-block; position:fixed;" id="userMenu" name="userMenu" scrolling="yes" frameborder="1" marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px" src="userMenu.php" /></iframe>
    </div>

    <div>
        <iframe style="top:160px; left:225px; width:100%; height:100%; border:2px blue; background-color:lightgrey; display:inline-block; position:fixed;" id="frameBody" name="frameBody" scrolling="yes" frameborder="1" marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px" src="<?= $sBody . (strlen($sURLParameterString) > 1 ? $sURLParameterString : '') ?>" allowfullscreen /></iframe>
    </div>

    <div style="float:right;">
        <iframe style="top:160px; right:0px; width:225px; height:100%; border:2px blue; background-color:grey; display:inline-block; position:fixed;" id="patientMenu" name="patientMenu" scrolling="yes" frameborder="1" marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px" src="patientMenu.php" /></iframe>
    </div>

    <div>
        <iframe style="bottom:0px; width:100%; height:40px; border:2px red; background-color:grey; display:block; position:fixed;" id="footerTitle" name="footerTitle" scrolling="no" frameborder="1" marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px" src="frameFooter - Kopie.php" /></iframe>
    </div>

    <?php
        }
    ?>

    </html>
```

Please mind that, of course, it is a good if not essential step to cast the `style="whatever"` statements into an external CSS file, but this is not necessary here to show you what I mean.

It is important not to change the `name="something"` statements from frames to iframes as they are needed for the referral of, for instance, a menu link referring to the above-mentioned code with `frameBody` (see there):

```
    [... preceding code ...]

    <li><a target="frameBody" href="dothis.php">Do this</a></li>
    <li><a target="frameBody" href="dothat.php">Do that</a></li>
    <li><a target="frameBody" href="dosomethingcompletelydifferent.php">Do something completely different</a></li>

    [... further code ...]
```

The `allowfullscreen` is just an optional element in case one of these iframes should be made fullscreen using an appropriate javascript code (not supplied here).

And, finally, the change of both `<!DOCTYPE ...>` and `<html ...>` corresponds to being able to make use of HTML 5 instead of the older HTML 4 declaration which had to refer to a DTD (Document Type Definition).

I hope this bit of code helps in a generic way to root from HTML framesets to HTML iframes on the way to a frameless solution as next possible step.